# Why the synchronized method can be called by only two threads in turn?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a synchronized method in the class. The code within the try clause calls the `notifyAll()` and `wait()`. When I run the code, all threads are running according to the output. But it turns out to be only two threads call the method in turn. That's terrible.

I've tried to write a synchronized block in a while loop of a non-synchronized method, and it works well. Note that there are 5 threads in total.

Here's the synchronized method:

```java
private synchronized void sell() {
        while (ticketsLeft > 0) {
            try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "__________" + (ticketsLeft--));
                    this.notifyAll();
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

I've also tried to put the while loop in the synchronized block, same thing happened.

```
private void sell() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (ticketsLeft > 0) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "__________" + (ticketsLeft--));
                    this.notifyAll();
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

And it works like that, thread 3 and 4 calls the method in turn:

```
5__________100
1__________99
2__________98
3__________97
4__________96
3__________95
4__________94
3__________93
4__________92
3__________91
4__________90
3__________89
4__________88
3__________87
4__________86
3__________85
4__________84
3__________83
4__________82
3__________81
4__________80
```

With the synchronized block in the while loop within the non-synchronized method:

```java
    private void sell() {
        while (ticketsLeft > 0) {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "__________" + (ticketsLeft--));
                    this.notifyAll();
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                    this.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

And it works as I expected:

```
5__________100
3__________99
2__________98
1__________97
4__________96
1__________95
2__________94
3__________93
1__________92
4__________91
3__________90
2__________89
5__________88
2__________87
3__________86
4__________85
1__________84
3__________83
2__________82
5__________81
3__________80
```

Thank you guys for reading this question. I'm sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post images. I'd appreciate it if anyone has ideas about that.

Comment: Because the synchronization lock will be obtained by whatever thread happens to try to get it first after they're all awoken, and chance has it that with your specific configuration, it's the first two. If you want resources to be shared fairly with all threads, use a mechanism that balances it fairly. That's not at all the point of synchronized, on the contrary synchronized tries to be the most efficient, nowhere near the fairest.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here to properly answer the question. But I think it has something to do with the while loop being outside the synchronized block in the 2nd case and it first case the while loop inside the synchronized method.

All the thread will wait inside the while loop in the second method but for the first one they will wait outside the while loop.

Note: Both synchronized method and the synchronized method have lock on the current instance of the class on which your threads are running.

Hope this helps!! :-)

Comment: Thank you for helping me first, the full class file can be found here:  [gist](https://gist.github.com/ycfung/515b8441abb05487dca62bcbb48eb84a)